# unable to provide link of file in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I have created an ajax script in my codigniter the file main.js is located in localhost/website/assets/js/main.js

on main .js I had posted link to the file like this when I was testing in normal mode not on framework

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$("#post").on('submit', (function(e) {
    var form = this;
    $.ajax({
        url         : "includes/post_data.php",
        type        : "POST",
        data        : new FormData(this),
        contentType : false,
        cache       : false,
        processData : false,
        success     : function(data) {
            $("#data_update").prepend(data);
            form.reset();
        }
    });
}));
});
```

Now when I am making this similar functionality within codeigniter I have created a controller so How do I will be giving link as of now it wont be includes/get_data.php the controler which I have created is like this

```
class Forums extends CI_Controller {
   public function post_forum() {
      //code goes here
  }
}
```

When I tried to give link as 'mydirecotry/forums/post_forum' it states an error Please help me out

Comment: try to get `base_url()` in your js file first.

Comment: base_url can be get like this <?php echo base_url() ?> right but I beleive I cannot use php in .js file right ?

Comment: need to make some hidden field having base_url()'s value.

Comment: @MarkAlan can you explain this part ***Now when I am making this similar functionality within codeigniter I have created a controller so How do I will be giving link as of now it wont be includes/get_data.php the controler which I have created is like this***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Codeigniter try this:

```
url : "<?php echo base_url() ?>/post_forum",
```

**base_url()**

Returns your site base URL, as specified in your config file. Example:

```
echo base_url();
```

**Note:** In case you are working on individual JS file then pass the  to its value and get its value using JS or Jquery.

Comment: yes I was trying to do this but my script is in main.js php I beleive wont work in js file right?

Comment: I think in `core js(main.js)` file OP can not use php tag.Am i right @Mayank Pandeyz.

Comment: In that case put a hidden field inside form, in which pass the `<?php echo base_url() ?>` to its value and get its value using JS or Jquery.

Comment: @MayankPandeyz <input type="hidden" id="url" value="<?php echo base_url() ?>" /> like this ?

Comment: Yeah Mark, you can get its value using `$('#url).val();`

Comment: but don't you think it wont be a good approach as we are showing our controller link ?

Comment: It is already shown in network when ajax call initiates. If you don't want to use then put it in meta tag and use it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the full url of your controller.To check your full url, Run this code in any controller of your project.

Example:

```
class Forums extends CI_Controller {

   public function post_forum() {

      echo base_url('forums/post_forum');
  }
}
```

Browse this controller by your browser.It will generate the full link.
Like:
http://localhost/mydirecotry/forums/post_forum
Copy and paste the full link in your code url:

Comment: okay so like on every script i write I HAVE TO GIVE FULL URL ? we cannot just provide path like we do normally we provide path as /includes/filename

Comment: In codeigniter you will not get access of a php file like includes/filename .

Comment: generate your link by url: '<?php echo base_url('forums/post_forum'); ?>' in php file and for .js file pass the url by a hidden field , ajax links are always public .

Answer (score 0):

If you have not removed `index.php` from your url then, change the url in your jquery file to:

`url : <?php echo base_url('index.php/forums/post_forum') ?>,`

Or, if you have already removed `index.php` from your url then, change it to:

`url : <?php echo base_url('forums/post_forum') ?>,`

Also, in order to use `base_url()` method, you have to first, load url helper.